# Wordpress link on Facebook: no og:type warning in FB debugger

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

My website (http://www.guidoleurs.org) is finished, however if I want to share and promote it on social media I come across a problem. Somehow if I want to share my static frontpage on Facebook (by copy/pasting the link in a post) I only see “guidoleurs.org” without any information or image. Also beneath every blog post I have the Accesspress Social Share buttons, but if I want to use them to share a post, the Facebook post looks like “404 not found” (although the link works) without the featured image..

How can I fix this?

I also used the debug tool of Facebook and when I paste either link from my website in, I get the following result:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fguidoleurs.org%2F2015%2F08%2F27%2Fblog-1%2F

Comment: Both of the links http://www.guidoleurs.org and http://guidoleurs.org/2015/08/27/blog-1/ don't work for me. Are you still working on the website?

Comment: They should now. However the link to the blog post has changed: http://guidoleurs.org/publication-on-white-sharks/